# Is there a way to have a view with a working 'rails c' console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to be able to access the console without having to ssh into the production box...is there a way to have a view template that's just a working console?

Comment: Can you further explain why this would be needed? This would leave a large security hole in the application itself and typing `ssh user@host` is not very difficult and far more secure

Answer (score 3):

There is a [web-console](https://github.com/rails/web-console) gem. Make sure you secured access, it's quite risky to enable prod console on WWW.

Comment: Yes, Web console should be used in Development environment only.

In fact, the question should clarify the purpose of accessing the console in production. If the purpose is to debug, I think the better way is looking at the log for a certain error.